# Is Android's PreferencesActivity suitable for storing object instance data, such as in an app with multiple alarms?

Tags: android

I'm new to the Android API, but not to coding.  Trying to understand the correct way to approach a certain pattern that must come up all the time in Android.  Let's say i write an app like Alarm Clock Plus, with two defining features:

1. The (multiple) alarms are displayed in a list
2. I can click on a given alarm in that list to edit its settings (these are in a list similar to how standard Android system settings appear).

As for implementing (1), I assume that the alarm list is a ListView.  I'll deal with this later.

To implement (2), is it sensible / sane to use PreferencesActivity for the settings of each alarm, or is PreferencesActivity designed for app-wide settings?  PreferencesActivity is appealing as it seems to handle the loading and saving of data transparently (using SharedPreferences).  I'm just concerned that it's the wrong tool for the job.

(I currently have a working version, which uses just one alarm.  My main concern moving forward is to work out how to refactor the code to handle multiple alarms.)

Comment: For (1), I'd say that a ListView is perfect. For (2), I'd use a database.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the pros / cons of using a database as opposed to PreferencesActivity?  Doesn't using a database mean that I have to roll my own ListView as well, and handle getting / editing / saving of the settings that PreferencesActivity gives me "for free"?

Comment: Store the alarm's information in a database. That will be easier and quicker.

Comment: Well, as you pointed out, preferences are more suited for System Settings, and should contain little data. A db will offer a larger storage and more flexybility (imagine you want to list all the events scheduled for a particular date: just make a query and fill your ListView)

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, just trying to understand how that's better for this use case.  You mention 1) larger storage - but there isn't a lot of data to store here and 2) more flexibility - why do I need this?  Settings for a given alarm are not something I'd wish to query in a settings screen - I always know that for a given alarm I want e.g. the time, tone, volume etc...

But as two of you seem quite sure, I guess that's the decision made... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some good help in the comments, but no answers, so for the record / anyone else searching - a database is far more suitable for this task - PreferencesActivity is more for system settings.